# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is not working when doing axios post in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, cors

I am trying to post an object to API. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ciboservis.herokuapp.com/api/v1/filial/adm' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have read other questions and found out that I needed to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. So, here is my code now:

```
axios
  .post("https://ciboservis.herokuapp.com/api/v1/filial/adm", {testName: 'foo'}, {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })

  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

However, I am still getting the same error

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` this header needs to added from your server response and not from client who is requesting the resource. You can see if the response that you are getting when you hit this URL contains this header

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by Pratik in the comment, you need to apply these headers from the server side, which is hosted on Heroku.

Or For development purposes, you can install a chrome plugin to bypass this issue, but a long-term and better solution is to add this header on the server side

You can try this plugin - [CORS Bypass Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)